# Using boto3 and python3, I cannot base64 encode the JSON for ClientContext?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

In using lambda, the docs say you must send a base64 encoded JSON object for the ClientContext.  It also says Client Context must be a 'str' not bytes.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke

Since python3's base64 library now encodes using bytes, not string - this appears to have stumped me.

```
import boto3
import base64

CLIENT = boto3.client('lambda')

client_context = b'{ "client_name": "Andy"}'
encoded_context = base64.b64encode(client_context)
CLIENT.invoke(
        FunctionName='testFunction',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        LogType='Tail',
        ClientContext=encoded_context
    )
```

The error I get is:
`Invalid type for parameter ClientContext, value: b'eyAiY2xpZW50X25hbWUiOiJGUkVFSFVCIiB9', type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

or when I set `str(encoded_context)`:
`botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestContentException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Client context must be a valid Base64-encoded JSON object.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just convert your bytes data to string using decode("ascii") or decode("utf-8")

Answer (score 4):

The code below is an example for passing Client Context via boto3.

```
import boto3
import base64
import json

client = boto3.client("lambda")


def lambda_context(custom=None,
                   env=None,
                   client=None):
    client_context = dict(
        custom=custom,
        env=env,
        client=client)
    json_context = json.dumps(client_context).encode('utf-8')
    return base64.b64encode(json_context).decode('utf-8')

context = {
    "custom": {"foo": "bar"},
    "env": {"test": "test"},
    "client": {}
}

client.invoke(FunctionName="<YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTIONS>",
                         ClientContext=lambda_context(**context),
                         Payload=YOUR_PAYLOAD)
```

Note that *env* and *custom* in the Client Context dict object could be anything. For *client*, only the following keys can be accepted:

```
app_version_name
app_title
app_version_code
app_package_name
installation_id
```

Btw, if your lambda function is implemented in Python. The Client Context object may be referred as `context.client_context`. *env*(`context.cilent_context.env`) and *custom*(`context.client_context.custom`) are two dict objects. If any of *env*, *custom*, or *client* is not passed from boto3's invoke method, the corresponding one in the `context.client_context` would be a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Lambda.invoke() doesn't send client context · Issue #1388 · aws/aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1388):

```
var ctx = {
    custom: { foo: 'bar' },
    client: { snap: ['crackle', 'pop']},
    env: { fizz: 'buzz' },
};
la.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'contextPrinter',
    ClientContext: AWS.util.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(ctx)),
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({ baz: 'quux' })
}, function (err, data) { return console.log(err, data); });
```

While this is JavaScript rather than Python, it should give a general idea of how to encode `context`.